# tornadoweb include path from args

Tags: templates, python-3.x, tornado

I'm try include path of template from argv :

```
site_argv = {
    'template'  : 'site_list.html'
}
return self.base.render('site.html', **site_argv)
```

and site.html include from template variable:

```
{% include template %}
```

but error file template not fount, without include path from value variable

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/.../template/template'
```

I'm try

```
{% module Template(template, **kwargs) %}
```

but kwargs variable not found

I want include children template with use all parent template args when i don't known args of parent template.

Answer (score 0):

The tornado template system is based on code generation and requires that all `include` and `extend` directives use constants so the code can be generated once.

In general, Tornado templates have semantics similar to regular python code. The `module Template` directive is like calling another template file as a function, and just like regular python functions there is no (clean) way for a function to see the variables defined in the function that called it.

Instead, you should pass the arguments around as a single object. Call `render` with `self.base.render('site.html', argv=site_argv)` and then you can use `{% module Template(template, **argv) %}`